# Including all tokens in the term-document matrix in the R tm package

Tags: r, tm, term-document-matrix

I'm trying to make a term-document matrix with the `TermDocumentMatrix` function of the `tm` package in R and found that some words are not included.

```
> library(tm)
> tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource("The book is of great importance.")))
> rownames(tdm)
[1] "book"        "great"       "importance." "the"
```

Here, the words *is* and *of* have been excluded from the matrix. If the corpus only includes the deleted words, it gives the following message.

```
> tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource("of is of is")))
Warning message:
In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
> rownames(tdm)
NULL
```

The message signals that *is* and *of* are deleted before the matrix is built, but I have not been able to figure out why it occurs and how I can include all the tokens in the corpus.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the control argument of TermDocumentMatrix

```
require(tm)
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource("of is of is")), control =  list(stopwords=FALSE, wordLengths=c(0, Inf)))
rownames(tdm)
```

Comment: I checked the stopwords argument but hadn't looked at wordLength. Thank you!